# How can I generate a certificate at runtime on iOS to use with the SSLSetCertificate function?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, security, tls1.2

I am using the [BiAtoms/Socket.Swift](https://github.com/BiAtoms/Socket.swift) library that supports TLS on iOS.

Although the library supports importing a .p12 certificate, this is not what I require.

I need to generate a new certificate each time the application is launched and then pass this onto the library. The library passes a [CFArray] to the Apple's function [SSLSetCertificate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1392400-sslsetcertificate)

To generate a new key-pair I have found the library [SwiftyRSA](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA) that has a function "generateRSAKeyPair" that uses Apple's SecKeyCreateRandomKey function.

So in a nutshell what I am looking to achieve is, use the BiAtoms' Http.Swift library that uses his Socket.Swift library so that I can establish a TLS secured HTTPS server on iOS but at the same time I have to generate a new Certificate each time the app is run.

I am totally confused as to how I can generate (and store in memory) the [CFArray] that is ultimately required by SSLSetCertificate to secure the POSIX socket.